# Is it possible to have an infowindow pre-opened in when you load a Cartodb.js map?

Tags: carto

Can I code my Cartodb.js map somehow so that when someone first opens the map, there is already an infowindow open for them to see?

Answer (score 4):

There is actually a better way now,

https://gist.github.com/javisantana/7b817fda1e7511c451c7#file-index-html-L39

The key bit is the openInfowindow function,

```
  function openInfowindow(layer_index, latlng, cartodb_id) {
    layer.trigger('featureClick', null, latlng, null, { cartodb_id: cartodb_id }, layer_index);
  }
```

you can include it in your own code. Pass it the `layer` you are referencing, the `latlng` where you want the infowindow anchored, and the `cartodb_id` of the item you want opened.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use an Infobox [1] and then open it on map load. You can use custom templates like with Infowindows.

Another option is to fake a click event on a map feature, like a Marker.

I hope it makes sense. Please tell if you need more help.

[1] http://developers.cartodb.com/documentation/cartodb-js.html#sec-5-3

Comment: how would you fake a click event on a marker?

Comment: via jquery for example, with a `.click()`

Answer (score -1):

Another way is to call the features from your table upon loading. Then creating a div structure that will pick out the json features and display the results.

```
    sql.execute("SELECT house FROM table_name WHERE distance ='5')
     .done(function(data) {
      for (var i = 0; i < data.total_rows; i++) {
       $('#content').append("<div><p>" + data.rows[i].house + 
                                    </p></div>Distance:<div><p>" +                                                                            
                                               data.rows[i].distance +
                                   "</p></div>");
     }
  })
   .error(function(errors) {
    // errors contains a list of errors
     console.log("errors:" + errors);
   })
```

Next place div id='content' somewhere  in your html along with some css to make it appear.

Maybe something like this:

```
    #content.p{ 
        position: absolute;
        z-index:10000;
        background:#fff;
        margin:0 auto;
        padding:0;
        height: 50px;
        width: 100px;
        }
```

I have not tested the code but the [logic/structure](https://github.com/Vizzuality/CartoDB-Tutorials/blob/master/cartodb-js/basic_data_queries.md) is here